# CodeRay adds incorrect indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, coderay

I am using CodeRay version 1.1.1 to render a ruby file. However, it is adding a large number of extra spaces to indent all lines except the first line.

As a MCVE, I have a file called something.rb with contents:

```
# This comment will not be indented
# This comment WILL be indented
```

In the controller I have:

```
contents = File.read('something.rb')
@syntax_highlighted = CodeRay.scan(contents, :ruby).div
```

And in the view, I have

```
= raw @syntax_highlighted
```

However, for an output I receive as seen here: [image: Incorrect output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by HAML messing with your whitespace. See HAML's documentation on [Whitespace Preservation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_preservation).

> Sometimes you don’t want Haml to indent all your text. For example, tags like pre and textarea are whitespace-sensitive; indenting the text makes them render wrong.

You'll need to use `~` instead of the usual `=` so your view would be:

```
~ raw @syntax_highlighted
```

Comment: It works properly, thanks for helping me work through this :)